# How to get dynamically changed Key's value in Json String using java

Tags: java

I'm trying to parse Json string using java, I have stuck up with some scenario.

See below is my JSON String:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
                "Ports": {
            "8080/tcp": [   // It will change dynamically like ("8125/udp" and "8080/udp" etc....)
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

I try to parse the above json string by using the following code:

```
JsonObject NetworkSettings_obj=(JsonObject)obj.get("NetworkSettings");
if(NetworkSettings_obj.has("Ports"))
                {
                    JsonObject ntw_Ports_obj=(JsonObject)NetworkSettings_obj.get("Ports");
                    if(ntw_Ports_obj.has("8080/tcp"))
                    {
                        JsonArray arr_ntwtcp=(JsonArray)ntw_Ports_obj.get("8080/tcp");                          
                        JsonObject ntwtcp_obj=arr_ntwtcp.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
                        if(ntwtcp_obj.has("HostIp"))
                        {
                            ntw_HostIp=ntwtcp_obj.get("HostIp").toString();
                            System.out.println("Network HostIp = "+ntw_HostIp);
                        }
                        if(ntwtcp_obj.has("HostPort"))
                        {
                            ntw_HostPort=ntwtcp_obj.get("HostPort").toString();                     
                            System.out.println("Network HostPort = "+ntw_HostPort);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ntw_HostIp="NA";
                        ntw_HostPort="NA";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ntw_HostIp="NA";
                    ntw_HostPort="NA";
                }
```

In my code I have used this code

```
JsonArray arr_ntwtcp=(JsonArray)ntw_Ports_obj.get("8080/tcp");
```

to get the value of "8080/tcp"

How can I get the values of dynamically changing key like ("8125/udp","8134/udp", etc...)

**Note: I'm using gson library for parsing**

**After modification**

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonObject obj=(JsonObject)parser.parse(new FileReader("sampleJson.txt"));
            System.out.println("obj = "+obj);
            JsonObject NetworkSettings_obj=(JsonObject)obj.get("NetworkSettings");
            if(NetworkSettings_obj.has("Ports"))
            {
                JsonObject ntw_Ports_obj=(JsonObject)NetworkSettings_obj.get("Ports");
                System.out.println("ntw_Ports_obj = "+ntw_Ports_obj);
                Object keyObjects = new Gson().fromJson(ntw_Ports_obj, Object.class);
                List keys = new ArrayList();
                System.out.println(keyObjects instanceof Map);  //**** here the statement prints false
                if (keyObjects instanceof Map)        // *** so controls doesn't enters into the if() condition block *** //
                {
                    Map map = (Map) keyObjects;
                    System.out.println("Map = "+map);
                    keys.addAll(map.keySet());
                    String key = (String) keys.get(0);
                    JsonArray jArray = (JsonArray) ntw_Ports_obj.get(key);
                    System.out.println("Array List = "+jArray);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem is the key `8080/tcp` is not fixed and it may change. when this situation you can try like this to get the value of the `Dynamic key`.

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = ntw_Ports_obj
                .entrySet();

for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entrySet) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    JsonArray jArray = (JsonArray) ntw_Ports_obj.get(key);
    System.out.println(jArray);
}
```

**Edit:**

```
Object keyObjects = new Gson().fromJson(ntw_Ports_obj, Object.class);
List keys = new ArrayList();

/** for the given json there is a one json object within the 'Ports' so the 'keyObjects' will be the 'Map'**/
if (keyObjects instanceof Map) {
    Map map = (Map) keyObjects;
    keys.addAll(map.keySet());
    /**
     * keys is a List it may contain more than 1 value, but for the given
     * json it will contain only one value
     **/
    String key = (String) keys.get(0);
    JsonArray jArray = (JsonArray) ntw_Ports_obj.get(key);
    System.out.println(jArray);
}
```

Comment: I have mentioned above I'm using gson library, the keySet() method is not available in gson. @ksap

Comment: Then you can use `entrySet()` check my new answer

Comment: Thanks for reply, It's working in new jdk versions, but in my working area we are using older version jdk(1.3) so it is not supported for generics(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>) and for-loop(for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entrySet)). I have to compile my code in older version.

Comment: I doesn't work it give me an error like below: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(Unknown Source) at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source) at InspectParsing.main(InspectParsing.java:610) @ksap

Comment: Is it any method available to directly get the key from Json String in gson library? ie.,"8080/tcp". Like JSONObject.keySet(); in JSON simple library.

Comment: In your code, the didn't enter into the codition if (keyObjects instanceof Map) @ksap

Comment: @KaviChinna code just worked on given `json`. just get the functionality of finding the key value from the given answer and use it according to your requirements. _again it worked to the given `json`_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79029/discussion-between-ksap-and-kavi-chinna).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that (not tested but should be ok) :

```
if (ntw_Ports_obj.isJsonArray()) {

   Iterator it = ntw_Ports_obj.getAsJsonArray().iterator();

   while (it.hasNext()) {

     JsonElement element = (JsonElement) it.next();

     if(element.isJsonArray()){

      JsonArray currentArray = element.getAsJsonArray();

      // Do something with the new JsonArray...

     }

   }
 }
```

Comment: It gives an error like "Cannot cast from JsonObject to JsonArray", I don't want Generics that is Iterator<JsonElement>, because I'm using old version jdk.